# Disable Category Page Description Content from showing on Additional Pages

Tags: magento-1.9, category, template, ce-1.9.2.4

How can we remove the category descriptions for "additional pages".. like

http://www.uretilalt.dk/herreure?p=10

For instance?

Manage to remove from filtered results, but can't figures this part out?

Magento ver. 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid displaying category descriptions, there are two possibilities

### Via the backend

You'll need to edit every single category and remove the description manually.

### Via the templates

Edit `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/catalog/category/view.phtml` and replace the following code:

```
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
<div class="category-description std">
    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

With:

```
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <?php $page = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('p'); ?>
    <?php if (!$page): ?>
        <div class="category-description std">
            <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for commenting.. that code removes all categories, we want to have it on the "base" http://www.uretilalt.dk/herreure but not on all additional pages like http://www.uretilalt.dk/herreure?p=1 + 2 + 3 etc..

Comment: @JonasLyngholm ok I understand now see my updated answer

Comment: I think there's an error somewhere? Tried with and without the "double <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>" - but end up with a almost blank page (just top header left?)

Comment: @JonasLyngholm I'll check that out tomorrow and let you know but that's definitely the logic you need to follow

Comment: @JonasLyngholm just made the test on my own website and it works perfectly with the code I pasted. Ensure you did the replace the right bit of original code and did not miss or remove anything else

Comment: @JonasLyngholm great feel free to mark the question as answered so it will benefit for others

Comment: Raphael do you know how to fix this as well: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122141/disable-category-page-description-content-from-showing-on-sorted-results