# Disable Category Page Description Content from showing on Sorted Results

Tags: magento-1.9, category, sorting

Our category pages the description attribute shows at the top of the page. This section is really helpful for the initial category experience.

Problem:
When the user sorting in the category, the description still displays.

Question:
How can we limit the description from only showing on the non-sorted version of the category page?

Eg. show on:
http://www.uretilalt.dk/dameure

Hide on:
http://www.uretilalt.dk/dameure?dir=asc&limit=36&mode=grid&order=name